# Next.js 13 app is failing to prerender a page when using Docker inside DigitalOcean VPS

Tags: postgresql, docker, next.js, digital-ocean

I have built a very simple full stack note taking using Next.js v13, TypeScript, DrizzleORM, and PostgreSQL database. I am familiar using the technologies, but where I wanted to push myself a bit and learn more about was to switch up my deployment process, and learn how to use a VPS, to which I chose DigitalOcean. I have already setup a Droplet as well. My database is currently local, and I am using DBeaver as my admin tool of choice. Locally, everything is working just fine.

Ideally, what I want to achieve is to put the entire project (next.js app + db) into a Docker container, and deploy that to the web. I am new to using Docker + DigitalOcean, so please let me know if that is even possible.

The issue that I am having is that during the build process on the VPS (which I've SSH'd into), it fails when trying to pre-render my `/notes` page.

Here is the code for that page:

```
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";
import { z } from "zod";

import { db } from "@/drizzle/config";
import { notes } from "@/drizzle/schema";

const schema = z.object({
  name: z.string().nonempty(),
  content: z.string().nonempty()
});

const getNotes = async () => {
  try {
    const nts = await db.select().from(notes);

    return nts;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Something went wrong when fetching notes!");
  }
};

const NotesPage = async () => {
  const createNote = async (formData: FormData) => {
    "use server";

    // validate data
    const validated = schema.parse({
      name: formData.get("name"),
      content: formData.get("content")
    });

    try {
      await db.insert(notes).values({
        name: validated.name,
        content: validated.content
      });

      revalidatePath("/notes");

      return {
        message: "Note created successfully!",
        revalidated: true,
        now: Date.now()
      };
    } catch (error) {
      return {
        message: "Something went wrong when creating the note!"
      };
    }
  };

  const nts = await getNotes();

  if (!nts) {
    return <p>No notes to display.</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-4xl">NotesPage</h1>

      <form
        className="inline-flex items-start flex-col space-y-4 border-solid border-black border-2 p-4 mt-2 w-80"
        action={createNote}
      >
        <div className="w-full">
          <label htmlFor="name" className="block">
            Name:
          </label>

          <input
            id="name"
            name="name"
            type="text"
            className="border-solid border-black border-2 block w-full"
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div className="w-full">
          <label htmlFor="content" className="block">
            Content:
          </label>

          <textarea
            id="content"
            name="content"
            className="border-solid border-black border-2 block w-full"
            required
          />
        </div>

        <button
          className="border-solid border-black border-2 py-1 px-4 hover:bg-black hover:text-white w-full"
          type="submit"
        >
          Create Note
        </button>
      </form>

      <div className="mt-4">
        <h2 className="text-2xl">Notes</h2>

        <ul className="grid gap-4 grid-cols-12">
          {nts.length
            ? nts.map((nt) => (
                <li key={nt.id} className="bg-yellow-200 col-span-2 p-4 rounded-lg">
                  <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold mb-1">{nt.name}</h3>
                  <p>{nt.content}</p>
                </li>
              ))
            : null}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NotesPage;
```

I am using the new experimental server actions to submit the POST request to the db, and insert a row. I have updated my `next.config.js` to this:

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    serverActions: true
  },
  output: "standalone"
};
```

Here is my current `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

# You only need to copy next.config.js if you are NOT using the default configuration
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry.
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

And here is my current `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production

  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "${POSTGRES_USERNAME}"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}"
      POSTGRES_DB: "${POSTGRES_DATABASE}"
```

Within the repo on the VPS, I do have a .env file setup with the necessary variables, and I've verified that by running `cat .env`.

After sometime debugging, I realized that I hadn't created the same database and table within the VPS as I have locally. And I confirmed this by entering the PostgreSQL CLI by running `sudo -u postgres psql`, and then, running `\l`. I then created the `postgres` database by running `CREATE DATABASE postgres`, and then because I am using Drizzle, I ran `npm run generate` and `npm run push`. Here are those 2 scripts in my package.json:

```
...
"generate": "drizzle-kit generate:pg",
"push": "drizzle-kit push:pg",
...
```

I then inserted a row into the notes database by running `INSERT INTO notes (name, content) VALUES ('YourName', 'YourContent');`, after which I ran `SELECT * FROM notes;` and here is the output from that:

```
                  id                  |   name   |   content   |         created_at         
--------------------------------------+----------+-------------+----------------------------
 74ccdfc8-bc78-4714-9eb9-45adb8027b08 | YourName | YourContent | 2023-10-04 04:56:52.444413
(1 row)
```

Finally, here is the error message I see in the terminal:

```
# docker compose up -d
[+] Building 67.8s (15/20)                                                                                                                                    docker:default
 => [web internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.07kB                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [web internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 113B                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [web internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:16-alpine                                                                                                   0.6s
 => [web internal] load build context                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2.36kB                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [web deps 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:16-alpine@sha256:a1f9d027912b58a7c75be7716c97cfbc6d3099f3a97ed84aa490be9dee20e787                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [web builder 2/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [web runner 3/9] RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [web runner 4/9] RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [web deps 2/5] RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [web deps 3/5] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [web deps 4/5] COPY package.json package-lock.json ./                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [web deps 5/5] RUN npm install                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [web builder 3/5] COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules                                                                                          0.0s
 => [web builder 4/5] COPY . .                                                                                                                                          0.1s
 => ERROR [web builder 5/5] RUN npm run build                                                                                                                          66.9s
------                                                                                                                                                                       
 > [web builder 5/5] RUN npm run build:                                                                                                                                      
1.528                                                                                                                                                                        
1.528 > note-taker@0.1.0 build                                                                                                                                               
1.528 > next build                                                                                                                                                           
1.528                                                                                                                                                                        
2.952 Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
2.953 This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
2.953 You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
2.953 https://nextjs.org/telemetry
2.954 
3.090    Creating an optimized production build ...
28.72  ✓ Compiled successfully
28.73    Linting and checking validity of types ...
38.03    Collecting page data ...
66.43    Generating static pages (0/6) ...
   Generating static pages (1/6) 
   Generating static pages (2/6) 
   Generating static pages (4/6) 
66.69 Error: Something went wrong when fetching notes!
66.69     at f (/app/.next/server/app/notes/page.js:1:3246)
66.69     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
66.69     at async y (/app/.next/server/app/notes/page.js:1:3439)
66.71 
66.71 Error occurred prerendering page "/notes". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
66.71 Error: Something went wrong when fetching notes!
66.71     at f (/app/.next/server/app/notes/page.js:1:3246)
66.71     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
66.71     at async y (/app/.next/server/app/notes/page.js:1:3439)
 ✓ Generating static pages (6/6) 
66.75 
66.75 > Export encountered errors on following paths:
66.75   /notes/page: /notes
66.79 npm notice 
66.79 npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.4 -> 10.2.0
66.80 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.2.0>
66.80 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.2.0` to update!
66.80 npm notice 
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

I spent a solid few hours trying to debug this, and I've looked at countless Docker configuration files online, but still I am stuck here. I would really appreciate some help and direction on this. Here is a link to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/andrews1022/note-taker) as well.

Thank you!

UPDATE: I figured out the solution - I created a database cluster on DigitalOcean, then when I SSH'd into my VPS, I made sure to include the information about that Database information instead of my local one on localhost:5432 in the .env file. The next app and db containers are working as expected.

Comment: your dockerfile can be improved. see https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-docker-multi-env for 2 `Dockerfile` examples of development & production.